# Helper for DropDown List in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm creating ASP.NET MVC application and I have problem with my dropdowns in "Register" page.

First, my **model** (Created by EF in "database first" mode):

```
public partial class User()
{
    ...
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
}

public partial class Country()
{
    ...
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

**NOTE**: User and Country are related by CountryId (is not a collection)

In my **controller**:

```
ViewBag.countries = context.Countries.ToList();

return View();
```

In my **view**:

```
<select name="CountryId" id="CountryId">
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.countries)
    {
        <option value="@item.Id" id="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
    }
</select>
```

So, I think that I need use this helpers:

```
@Html.DropDownList
@Html.DropDownListFor
```

But it's imposible doing work...

The **default code** of ASP.NET for views is:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryId, "CountryId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("CountryId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

And this code throws this error:

*Additional information: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'CountryId'.*

Any suggestions? **Thanks in advance**!!

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.  Tell us what is actually happening.

Comment: Thanks, I complete the question with more information about the topic

Comment: The error seems self-explanatory.

Comment: Instead of `ViewBag.countries = context.Countries.ToList();`, try to put this in ViewData. e.g. `ViewData["CountryId"] = context.Countries.ToList();`